# stereo_image_proc/processor.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros-groovy, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Groovy, I get this error when compiling a project, using catkin_make, that uses stereo_image_proc.  I went to /opt/ros/groovy/include/stereo_image_proc, and indeed, it only contains one file: DisparityConfig.h.  Why is this the case?  Where did the other header files go?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58316/stereo_image_proc/processor.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [ideasrule](https://answers.ros.org/users/4443/ideasrule/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like a bug to me. That include file is not getting installed by the catkin CMakeLists.txt.

Please [open an issue](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues) so this gets fixed.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0